# Router outputs "Bad IP address or host name" when trying to SSH from Linux terminal

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, virtual-network, gns3

I'm a total beginner in networking knowledge in general. Tried posting this in the Network Engineering Stack Exchange but they sent me here. My main goal is to be able to simulate a device so I can SSH into it from a Python application and get the output of the commands. But first, I'm trying to manually SSH into the device from the terminal.

I'm using GNS3 to simulate the network and a CISCO C7200 image. I'm using Manjaro Linux. My topology:

[image]

Router config:

```
conf t
hostname R1
ip domain-name local
crypto key generate rsa
ip ssh version 2
line vty 0 4
transport input ssh
login local
exit
username admin password 1234
exit
```

From a terminal, I can telnet into it just fine running:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 5001`

But when I run:

`ssh admin@127.0.0.1 -p 5001`

the terminal hangs and the R1 console outputs this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so just for completeness, affirm that you installed openssh-server

Comment: I dont follow parts if this pisr, but maybe can provide a couple of clues - 1.  SSH and telnet are different proticols. If you get a session (rather then an SSH banner when you use telnet - as seems to be the case here - it means telnet, not ssh is not running on that port. 2. It appears that the R1 device is trying to do an IP address lookup on SSH-2.0... (and failing)  which means its processing ssh negotiation as if it were a command.  So the issue is you habe telnet, not ssh running on port 5001.

Comment: @Yorik yes, I have it. `ssh -v` outputs: "OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023"

Comment: @davidgo That's very weird, given that I'm explicitly telling the router to use SSH with `transport input ssh`. Maybe I have a broken router image?

Comment: I don't know about the CISCO C7200 shell, but I postulate that you would have ssh running on port 22 (if its running at all) - nothing in your config tells it to bind to port 5001 - so why would it?

Comment: @davidgo exactly, that question is hammering my mind because I'm a total noob in this. I know SSH runs on port 22, but I'm specifying the 5001 port because GNS3 tells me that the router is accessible in port 5001 of localhost. So how else could I point SSH into the right IP address?

Comment: I'm struggling to format this comment and don't know much about CISCO -  but have a look at the 4th post at https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/login-to-router-switches-via-secure-shell/td-p/1407860  - [quote]ip ssh port 5001 rotary 1 3

line vty 0
 login local
 rotary 1
 transport input ssh
line vty 1
 login local
 rotary 2
 transport input ssh
line vty 2
 login local
 rotary 3
 transport input ssh[/quote]

Comment: what happens if you just try to connect to it on port 22 rather then 5001?   (Assuming there are no firewall rules stopping you?)

Comment: thanks @davidgo tried the solution you shared but no success. When I try to `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 22` it throws `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`. What's bugging me is that it really looks like by doing `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 5001` I'm able to reach the router, but it just tries to run `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5` into the router console, which is not a command that it understands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot connect to `localhost:5001` with SSH because there is no SSH server running on `localhost:5001`. As GNS3 is telling you, there is a Telnet server running there, not SSH. So, you need to connect using Telnet.

You seem to think that `localhost:5001` is some kind of magic port-forwarding and that somehow GNS3 is clever enough to figure out that you configured an SSH server on port 22 on your switch that it would magically NAT that into port 5001 on the host. But consider this: how would GNS3 know that you have an SSH server running on the switch and that you want to connect to it, rather than, say, an HTTP server?

`localhost:5001` is GNS3's way to give you access to the *terminal* of the switch. If you want to run any kind of services on the switch and connect to them over the network, you need to set up the appropriate networking so you can connect to the virtual switch's management IP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Before I tried using `localhost:5001` as the address for the SSH connection, I was indeed trying to setup the networking, and set up an interface inside the router using the same subnet of my WiFi adapter. This seemed to work, I could ping the router from outside GNS3. The problem was that SSH was throwing a `Authentication Failed (publickey, password)`  error, so I figured I should just try without setting up the networking. I will open another question regarding this and share it here.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1816818/permission-denied-when-trying-to-ssh-into-cisco-virtual-router) is the link for my new question regarding the SSH Permission Denied. Would gladly appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks.